# Can I delete the ‘for’ in the sentence ‘They would have completed the job in a few hours if not for the hard layer of rock.’?

Tags: grammar

Can I delete the ‘for’ in the sentence ‘They would have completed the job in a few hours if not for the hard layer of rock.’ ?

Comment: Why do you ask? What do you think?

Comment: @RonaldSole Is this sentence right: They would have completed the job in a few hour if not the hard layer of rock?

Comment: No, it's wrong. **For** is required. The expression is **if not for**, meaning that something would have been done if it had not been prevented by some factor. And it's in a few **hours** not "hour".

Comment: @RonaldSole Thanks. I have corrected my faults.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can delete the *for*.

However, doing so would change the meaning of the sentence to something ambiguous—each interpretation having a meaning different than the original. It would also make it sound strange.

> ❔ They would have completed the job in a few hours if not the hard layer of rock.

This could mean one of two things:

1. They would have completed the job in a few hours—even if they would not have completed the hard layer of rock.

This says that the job is somehow related to a hard layer of rock, but that completing the rock (whatever that entails) isn't a requirement of calling the job itself complete. (In this same way that *finishing your burger*—the job of finishing dinner—may not require that you also *finish your fries*.

2. They would have completed the job in a few hours—even if the hard layer of rock wouldn't.

This says that they are working on completing the job *as is* a hard layer of rock. Whether or not this is meaningful, it's one interpretation that the syntax leads to.  So even if the other party (a rock in this *specific* sentence, but it could be a person in a different sentence) wouldn't complete the job in the time period, *they* would.

Answer (score 0):

> They would have completed the job in a few hours if not for the hard layer of rock.

For represents the So for the If

Here is a saying I like saying, "If you have an If, You Need a So, So it works."

All sentences with an If need a So to represent it or it will sound incorrect and will not work as a professional sentence

(Just to clear things up, **So** would NOT work with an If, it represents a Cause and Effect, its Illiterate)

Just look at the sentence without a for.

> They would have completed the job in a few hours if not the hard layer of rock.

NOW, if you Require it gone, there is another option, you will need to change the sentence a little, Like the Examples below:

> They would have completed the job in a few hours if there wasn't a large layer of rock.
>
> They would have completed the job in a few hours if there wasn't a large layer of rock there.

Comment: What is the difference between your last two sentences?

Comment: @Y.zeng using a There at the end of the sentence may add a more Physical tone to it, referencing a place for the layer of rock, rather than just saying a layer of rock